# How to resolve ANR problem occured in SensorEventListener operating separete thread?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, android-thread, android-handlerthread

I'm noob at Java Android Programming(actually I'm noob at overall computer programming). I intended to make SensorEventListener of Accelometer sensor in a thread separate from main thread at Service. onSencorChanged method works well in separate thread, however, not long after operating Service, ANR occurs. Although ANR occurs, if I don't terminate at the point of ANR occures and press 'wait' to keep application running, the application goes well as I intended.
I have been tried to find how to resolve the problem for a long time, but I can't finally make my application stop occuring ANR.

This is my code using HandleThread.

```
public class SwingArmSensorService extends Service {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    private AccelerometerListenerInService listener;
    private HandlerThread mSensorThread;
    private Handler mSensorHandler;
    private static SuperActivityUsingServiceMain activity;
    private int mSteps;
    private final String SWING_SENSOR_INTENT_STEP_DATA_NAME = "steps";

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }
        mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("Sensor Thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); //
        mSensorThread.start(); //
        mSensorHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper());
        listener = new AccelerometerListenerInService();
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(listener, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, mSensorHandler);
        mSteps = intent.getIntExtra(SWING_SENSOR_INTENT_STEP_DATA_NAME, 0);
        Looper.loop();

        ...
    }
    private class AccelerometerListenerInService implements SensorEventListener {
        private Handler mainHandler;

        private float previousY, currentY;
        private float x, y, z;

        private final float THRESHOLD = 10f;

        public AccelerometerListenerInService() {
            mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2];
            currentY = y;

            if (Math.abs(currentY - previousY) > THRESHOLD) {
                mSteps++;
                // Handle UI at main thread here
                mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activity.setTextView(mSteps);
                    }
                });
            }

            previousY = y;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }
    }
}
```

I intended to show you only a partion related to question of code, but it's first time to post a question Stack Overflow, so if my code is too long I'm sorry.

Comment: Here you can read about Services and understand how they should work:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause**

In Android, a Service is running on the main thread which already has a Looper assign with it. In your code, when the service is started, it calls `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` on the main thread, it will cause unexpected behavior with your app.

**Solution**

Delete the following code from `SwingArmSensorService` class

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
    Looper.prepare();
}

Looper.loop();
```

As the result, your code will be:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mSensorThread = new HandlerThread("Sensor Thread", Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); //
    mSensorThread.start(); //
    mSensorHandler = new Handler(mSensorThread.getLooper());
    listener = new AccelerometerListenerInService();
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(listener, mSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, mSensorHandler);
    mSteps = intent.getIntExtra(SWING_SENSOR_INTENT_STEP_DATA_NAME, 0);
    ...
}
```